# Emacs rectangle space removal

Tags: emacs, rectangles

I have something like the following data set

```
A, B  ,C,D ,  E 
A1 , B121  ,C1,D1 ,  E1 
A2,Ber2  ,C2,D2 ,  E2 
A3, Bat3  ,C3,D3 ,  E3
```

And I want the commas to align so that they are right after the text ends and there is a space after which the next column starts. 
Like this

```
A, B, C, D, E 
A1, B121, C1, D1, E1 
A2, Ber2, C2, D2, E2 
A3, Bat3, C3, D3, E3
```

I tried using delete-whitepsace-rectangle but that only works as long as the width of the strings ina  column match for some reason . 
Is there a way to make this happen in emacs?

Comment: Making the commas "align" would suggest that they always appear at the same columns in each line of text. In your desired output, the commas of the first line do not align with the commas of the subsequent lines. I don't think you want alignment or rectangle operations; I think you just want to do a regexp replacement of `\s-*,\s-*` => `, ` (n.b. I used `\s-`, which matches any character of whitespace syntax, because actual space characters would be less apparent in this comment; but you could quite likely just type a space for each of those.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to replace spaces, a comma, and spaces, with a comma and a single space.

You can do this with `replace-regexp`, replacing "`\ *,\ *`" with "`,`".

Comment: Is there a way to do this over a selected rectangular region? what if I wanted this to apply only on column 2 ?